# Multi index groupby count including NaN values in pandas and, calculate percentage by single groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a df as shown below.

df:

```
Country       Player
Arg           Messi
Bra           Neymar
Arg           NaN
Arg           Messi
Arg           Aguero
Arg           Messi
Bra           Ronaldo
Spain         Xavi
Spain         NaN
Spain         NaN
Bra           Rivaldo
Spain         Iniesta
Bra           NaN
Spain         Xavi
```

Where NaN stands for information not available.
From the above df, I would like to perform multiple groupby counts as shown below.

Expected output:

```
Country    Player    Counts    Percentage_of_country
Arg        NaN       1         20
Arg        Messi     3         60
Arg        Aguero    1         20
Bra        Neymar    1         25
Bra        NaN       1         25
Bra        Ronaldo   1         25
Bra        Rivaldo   1         25
Spain      NaN       2         40
Spain      Xavi      2         40 
Spain      Iniesta   1         20
```

I tried below code:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Country', 'Player']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
df2['prcntg'] = df2['counts']/df2.groupby('Country')['counts'].transform('sum')
df2
```

Comment: @Corralien, that solution might have worked if the grouping was on single level.

Comment: A bit late seeing this post.  You can also take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do it, really producing all results in a single `groupby` is as follows:

Define a helper function to calculate the percentage:

with `dropna=False` to keep the `NaN` values:

```
f = lambda x: x.size / df.groupby('Country', dropna=False).size()[x.iloc[0]] * 100
```

The first `size` function returns counts under the group of `['Country', 'Player']`, while the second `size` function, which is grouped under `Country` only, returns the counts under the bigger group.

Then, make use of the [`named aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) of [`DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
(df.groupby(['Country', 'Player'], dropna=False)
   .agg(counts=('Player', 'size'), 
        prcntg=('Country', f))
)
```

**Result:**

```
                 counts  prcntg
Country Player                 
Arg     Aguero        1    20.0
        Messi         3    60.0
        NaN           1    20.0
Bra     Neymar        1    25.0
        Rivaldo       1    25.0
        Ronaldo       1    25.0
        NaN           1    25.0
Spain   Iniesta       1    20.0
        Xavi          2    40.0
        NaN           2    40.0
```

### Edit

If you got error `TypeError: groupby() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dropna'`, probably your Pandas version is older than version ***1.1.0***. This dropna parameter, which allows you keeping the NaN counts, is supported since this version. Probably you should consider upgrading your Pandas for richer sets of Pandas features.

If you cannot upgrade at the moment, a workaround solution is to replace NaN in the Player column by some other text, eg. string '_NaN' or some special word before the grouping. You can restore its values after the grouping if you need to. Sample codes below:

```
import numpy as np

df['Player'] = df['Player'].fillna('_NaN')      # Set `NaN` values to string `_NaN`

# Main processing with all results produced in a single `groupby`:
f = lambda x: x.size / df.groupby('Country').size()[x.iloc[0]] * 100
df_out = (df.groupby(['Country', 'Player'], as_index=False)
            .agg(counts=('Player', 'size'), 
                 prcntg=('Country', f))
         )

df_out['Player'] = df_out['Player'].replace('_NaN', np.nan)     # restore `NaN` values
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  Country   Player  counts  prcntg
0     Arg   Aguero       1    20.0
1     Arg    Messi       3    60.0
2     Arg      NaN       1    20.0
3     Bra   Neymar       1    25.0
4     Bra  Rivaldo       1    25.0
5     Bra  Ronaldo       1    25.0
6     Bra      NaN       1    25.0
7   Spain  Iniesta       1    20.0
8   Spain     Xavi       2    40.0
9   Spain      NaN       2    40.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am facing an as shown below.
TypeError: groupby() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dropna'

Comment: @Danish  Is your Pandas version older than version 1.1.0 ?  This `dropna` parameter, which allows you keeping the `NaN` counts, is supported since this version.  Probably you should consider upgrade your Pandas for richer sets of features.

Comment: @Danish  If you cannot upgrade at the moment, I think a workaround solution is to replace NaN in the Player column by some other text, eg. string 'NaN' or some special word before the grouping.  You can restore its values after the grouping if you need to.  Let me know if you would like me to provide you some sample codes for this.

Comment: @Danish  See my edit above for the sample codes.   The solution maintains with all results produced in a single `.groupby` as your question says.

Comment: This answer would deserve more upvotes, thank you, although an explanation what `[x.iloc[0]]` in the first line of code does, would help me to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2):

First group the dataframe by `Country`, and `Player`, then call `size` for the count, and call `to_frame` passing the column name to create dataframe out of it. You also need to pass `dropna=True` since you want to include `NaN`.

After that, you can group the count by `level=0` then call `tranform` to get the sum for the levels, and divide the count by this value. You can call `reset_index` at last if needed.

```py
count=df.groupby(['Country', 'Player'], dropna=False).size().to_frame('Counts')
count['Percentage_of_country']=100*count/count.groupby(level=0).transform('sum')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                 Counts  Percentage_of_country
Country Player                                
Arg     Aguero        1                   20.0
        Messi         3                   60.0
        NaN           1                   20.0
Bra     Neymar        1                   25.0
        Rivaldo       1                   25.0
        Ronaldo       1                   25.0
        NaN           1                   25.0
Spain   Iniesta       1                   20.0
        Xavi          2                   40.0
        NaN           2                   40.0
```

The `dropna` parameter was introduced in pandas *version 1.1.0*, so if you are using a version older than that, you can first try to replace the `NaN` value to something else, then revert back to `NaN` after performing the required operation.

```py
df['Player'] = df['Player'].fillna('#!Missing!#')  #replace NaN by #!Missing!#'
count=df.groupby(['Country', 'Player']).size().to_frame('Counts')
count['Percentage_of_country']=100*count/count.groupby(level=0).transform('sum')
count.reset_index(inplace=True)
count['Player'] = count['Player'].replace({'#!Missing!#':float('nan')})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I facing an error while executing above codes.

Comment: TypeError: groupby() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dropna'

Comment: @Danish, It seems like you are using an older version, `dropna` parameter was introduced in version `1.1.0`